# How to separate a text file with String and Integers and send it to a constructor class

Tags: java, string, file, class, inheritance

This is the text file that I need to recognize the shape name and the length, width, radius and then send it to its constructor class. I have a triangle.java, rectangle.java, circle.java, and a shape.java(abstract class) all these classes have set and get methods for the width, length, radius and calculate its area. I need to read the numbers from this text file and send it to its appropriate class.

```
Rectangle
Red Rectangle
12.0
34.0
Rectangle
Square
12.0
12.0
Triangle
Right Triangle
3.0
4.0
5.0
Triangle
Right Triangle
3.0
4.0
1.0
Circle
Red Circle
2.5
```

what I have so far is this in my helper class

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(
            "/Users/jb/eclipse-workspace2/CSI201Projects/src/Project05/Shapes.txt"));

    ArrayList<Shape> list = new ArrayList<Shape>();

    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = line.split("\n");
        if (tokens[1].equals("Circle")) {
            Circle c = new Circle();
            float radius = Float.parseFloat(tokens[1]);
            c.setRadius(radius);
            String color = String.valueOf(tokens[2]);
            c.setName(color);
           // Boolean filled = Boolean.valueOf(tokens[3]);
            c.getArea();
          //  c.getArea();
            list.add(c);
            System.out.println(c.toString());
        } else if (tokens[1].equals("Rectangle")) {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
            float length = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
            r.setlength(length);
            float width = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
            r.setwidth(width);
            String name = String.valueOf(tokens[3]);
            r.setName(name);
           // Boolean filled = Boolean.valueOf(tokens[4]);
           // r.setFilled(filled);
            r.getArea();
            list.add(r);
            System.out.println(r.toString());
        }
```

But this is wrong because I get errors and it doesn't print or calculate. I don't know how to fix it. This is my main abstract shape class.

```
abstract class Shape{
    String name;
    //public abstract double area();
    public Shape() {
        name=this.getClass().getName();
        //this.name= name;
    }
    
    public Shape(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }
    
    public String getName(String name) {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }
    
    //public abstract double area();
    
    public double getArea() {
        return getArea();
    }


    public String toString() {
        //return super.toString()+ this.name;
        //return "\nShape: "+ name+ "\n";
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName() ;
    
    }
    
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if (!(obj instanceof Shape)){
            return false;
        }
        
        Shape other = (Shape)obj;
        return (this.name).equalsIgnoreCase(other.name);
    }
}
```

This is one of my subclasses for `rectangle.java`

```
class Rectangle extends Shape{
    double width;
    double length;
    
    public Rectangle() {
        super("Rectangle");
        width=1.0;
        length=1.0;
    }
    
    public Rectangle(double w, double l, String name) {
        super(name);
        length= l;
        width= w;
        
    }
    
    public double getwidth() {
        
        return width;
    }
    public void setwidth( double w) {
        
        width=w;
    }
    
    public double getlength() {
        //return this.length;
        return length;
    }
    
    public void setlength( double l) {
        length=l;
    }
    

    public double getArea() {
        return length*width;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString()+ " \nLength: " + length+ " \nWidth: " +width+ " \nArea: " + getArea();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if (!(obj instanceof Rectangle)){
            return false;
        }
        
        Rectangle other = (Rectangle)obj;
        return super.equals(obj)&& this.width == other.width && this.length == other.length;
        
    }
```

Comment: You said "But this is wrong because I get errors", but you haven't posted what the error messages are. From a quick look at your code, I suspect you are getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`s because a) you are assuming that arrays are indexed from 1 but they are actually indexed from 0, and b) you only have 1 token per line anyway (except the colour line), and c) splitting a single line (read by nextline()) on `\n`s isn't going to do anything.

Comment: It would help you to be able to understand the error messages. This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors